Entry field as sorting option
I want to sort an "category page" based on a field set in the entry.
Eg. website about cocktails, on page x i want to sort by invention date and on page y I want to sort the cocktails based on their score.
What is the most elegant way to set this up in craftcms?

Example query, replace handles of section and fields
PAGE X
{% set query = craft.entries().section('cocktails').orderBy('inventionDate DESC') %}

PAGE Y
{% set query = craft.entries().section('cocktails').orderBy('score DESC') %}

